# CFArrayAppendValue crashes : EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)

Tags: ios, crash

I am analyzing crash reports of my app. It seems I have an issue with CFArrayAppendValue.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000000000defe
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x330f8268 __CFTypeCollectionRetain
1   CoreFoundation                  0x330619ca _CFArrayReplaceValues
2   CoreFoundation                  0x330618ba CFArrayAppendValue
```

I am trying to understand how a user can cause this crash, but it is not obvious for me. The code used is quite simple:

```
CFMutableArrayRef CFgroupMemberMutable = CFArrayCreateMutable (NULL,0,&kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
for (id key in [dataManager getSpecificGroupMembers:groupID]){
    ABRecordRef thisContact = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID (myAddressBook, [key intValue]);
    CFArrayAppendValue (CFgroupMemberMutable,thisContact);
}
```

Is it because I try to append a NULL value? (ABRecordRef does not exist?) Is the callback method used wrong?

Thanks for your help,
John John

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you try to append a NULL value using CFArrayAppendValue(), an exception will be thrown and you will get an EXC_BREAKPOINT. The default callback used in your example looks correct.

The ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID() may return NULL if the record in the address book is not found, so you must check for NULL, here is the updated code:

```
CFMutableArrayRef CFgroupMemberMutable = CFArrayCreateMutable (NULL,0,&kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
for (id key in [dataManager getSpecificGroupMembers:groupID]){
    ABRecordRef thisContact = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID (myAddressBook, [key intValue]);
    if (thisContact)
    {
        CFArrayAppendValue (CFgroupMemberMutable,thisContact);
    }
}
```